# How to avoid this Parallel Error

Tags: parallelization

I want parallelize one task, but got some stupid error. I don't know why i got it and how to fix it. I have 2 examples.
One works:

```
Do[s[a] = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .3}]
ListPlot[Table[{a, NIntegrate[y'[x]^2 /. s[a][[1]], {x, 0, 5}]}, {a, 
   1, 10, .3}], PlotRange -> All]
```

This fails:

```
Do[s[a] = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .3}]
ListPlot[ParallelTable[{a, 
   N[Integrate[y'[x]^2 /. s[a][[1]], {x, 0, 5}]]}, {a, 1, 10, .3}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Why? How can i fi it?
[image]
But if i change increment 0.3 to 0.5:

```
Do[s[a] = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .5}]
ListPlot[Table[{a, NIntegrate[y'[x]^2 /. s[a][[1]], {x, 0, 5}]}, {a, 
   1, 10, .5}], PlotRange -> All]

Do[s[a] = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
   y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .5}]
ListPlot[ParallelTable[{a, 
   N[Integrate[y'[x]^2 /. s[a][[1]], {x, 0, 5}]]}, {a, 1, 10, .5}], 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Both examples works fine. I can't understand this. Can i fix it?

Comment: First rule of debugging (or asking for debugging help here): reduce your code to the absolute smallest example that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: OK, I found the reason.  Will write an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this behaviour is that `Table` and `ParallelTable` generate the range from `1` to `10` by steps of `0.3` in slightly different ways.  You are working with inexact (floating point) numbers.  This means that even the slightest change in the order of arithmetic operations may change the result.  `(a+b) + c` may give a different result from `a + (b+c)`.

Obligatory reference:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Normally, Mathematica protects against this by allowing for a tolerance in `==`-comparisons.  But there is zero tolerance in pattern matching.  Only two exactly equal expressions will be treated the same by `MatchQ`.

For this reason it is not a very good idea to define `s[someNumber] = ...` like this.  Even without talking about precision, consider:

```
ff[1] = "a";
ff[1.] = "b";
ff[1.`10] = "c";
```

[image]

We have three different definitions for the three different kinds of numbers.  *Mathematically* they are equal.  But they are otherwise distinct expressions.

Thus,

```
1 == 1. == 1.`10
(* True *)
```

With [`SameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SameQ.html) there is already a difference, but it considers some of them to be the same:

```
{1 === 1., 1. === 1.`10, 1 === 1.`10}
(* {False, True, False} *)
```

For pattern matching, they're all different:

```
{MatchQ[1, 1.], MatchQ[1., 1.`10], MatchQ[1, 1.`10]}
(* {False, False, False} *)
```

Demonstration on your case:

```
s /@ ParallelTable[a, {a, 1, 10, 0.3}]

(* s[2.8] fails to match on my system *)

s /@ Range[1,10,0.3]

(* there's a match for every value on my system *)

alist = {}
a = 1.;
While[a <= 10,
 AppendTo[alist, a];
 a += 0.3;
 ]
s /@ alist

(* s fails to match for 1.9 on my system *)
```

---

**Workaround 1:**

```
rules = Table[
   a -> First@
     NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
      y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .3}];

nf = Nearest[rules]
```

`nf[1.]` now gives the match for `1.`.  This is a bit dangerous because it also gives the same match for `1.1` since `1.1` is nearest to `1.` out of the given points.

**Workaround 2:**

Use `Round` on `a` every time you set `s` or read `s`.  Choose the desired precision.  For example,

```
Do[s[Round[a, 0.001]] = 
   NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[a x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, 
    y, {x, 0, 5}], {a, 1, 10, .3}];
```

Then, use `s[Round[a,0.001]]` when you read `s` too.